# Can't Load display Json data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select dropdown which display the name of states.The data is getting fetched from php and is also available in controller JS file.But this data is appearing as blank in HTML.THe fetched result from php , shows the name of all states in table if consoled.log() is used.

HTML:

```
  <select class='form-control' name='state' id='state' ng-model='AddqueryArr.state' required='required'  ng-change='getCity(AddqueryArr.state)'>
                    <option></option>
                    <option ng-repeat='state in State.json' value='{{state.id}}'>{{state.name}}</option>
                </select>
```

JS:

```
servicePOST.send(appConstants.BASE_MS_URL + 'Activity/fetch-addquery.php?case=State').then(function(result) {
            $scope.State=result;
            console.log($scope.State);

        });
```

PHP:

```
 case "State":
$sql="select stateid,statename from state ";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $json_array=$obj->runQuery($result);

break;
```

Sample Output:[image: Sample Output]

Console.log:

[image: Console]

Comment: Show example of returned JSON. maybe it is not built correctly. The output of your `console.log()`

Comment: json: Array[34]
0: Object
$$hashKey: "object:154"
stateid: "1"
statename: "Andaman & Nicobar Islands"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
$$hashKey: "object:155"
stateid: "2"
statename: "Andhra Pradesh"
__proto__: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
6: Object
7: Object
8: Object
9: Object
10: Object
11: Object
12: Object
13: Object
14: Object

Comment: You key name is `statename` not name so use `state.statename` and same for the `id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Response Object you have `statename` and `stateid` not `name` and `id`.
Change your HTML as :

```
<select class='form-control' name='state' id='state' ng-model='AddqueryArr.state' required='required'  ng-change='getCity(AddqueryArr.state)'>
    <option></option>
    <option ng-repeat='state in State.json' value='{{state.stateid}}'>{{state.statename}}</option>
</select>
```